# How to expand array signature into parameter pack with template metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to expand an array signature into a size_t template parameter pack.

I am using an example from slide 24 of "Modern Template Metaprogramming: A Compendium", (Walter Brown, CppCon14)

Original, withouth parameter packs:
[image: [![Original, without parameter packs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6FIg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6FIg.png)]

And here is how I've modified it, in attempt to use parameter packs:
Note, I do not care about the unbounded case.

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template <class>
struct rank;

template <typename T,size_t n>
struct rank<T[n]> : std::integral_constant<size_t,1u> {};

template <typename T,size_t n,size_t... ns>
struct rank<T[n][ns]...> :
    std::integral_constant<size_t,1u+rank<T[ns]...>::value> {};
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You cannot declare multidimensional arrays with fold expressions. Best thing to do is stick to the recursive solution.

Comment: There is an exhaustive list of where pack expansions may appear (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.variadic#5) - simply put, your approach is impossible today.

Comment: After re-reading the question a couple of times, I'm not quite following why [`std::rank`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) doesn't work for you?

Comment: @The Dreams Wind    I'm trying to expand an array signature into a parameter pack of dimensions, trying to implement "rank" is just a simple example that has a historical basis.

Comment: The best way to do this is the solution you originally cited; parameter packs are of no help here. `1u+rank<T[ns]...>::value` doesn't make much sense; if you could match a multidimensional array with a parameter pack, the rank would be simply `sizeof...(ns)`, you wouldn't have needed recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, array bounds is not parameter pack expandable. Therefore, Without recursion, nothing can be done about the rank or extent of an array. Impossible is not answer to me, but I haven't found a proper solution yet. I guess it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure out a way to extract the array signature into a parameter pack, but it was not as straightforward as I hoped.

Below is my implementation, the first part is extracting the dimension parameter pack from the type. Then it simply calculates rank (in spirit of the original example) by finding the length of the parameter pack.

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t...>
struct SizeList {};

template <class,class sl>
struct dims_impl
{
    using type = sl;
};

template <typename T, size_t n, size_t... _n>
struct dims_impl<T[n],SizeList<_n...>>
{
    using type = typename dims_impl<T,SizeList<_n...,n>>::type;
};

template <typename T>
struct get_dims
{
    using type = typename dims_impl<T,SizeList<>>::type;
};

template <typename T, class dims>
struct rank_impl;

template <typename T, size_t... ns>
struct rank_impl<T,SizeList<ns...>>
{
    static constexpr size_t value = sizeof...(ns);
};

template <typename T>
struct rank
{
    static constexpr size_t value = rank_impl<T,typename get_dims<T>::type>::value;
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << rank<float[10][24][35][54]>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It's the same recursion as in the original, only instead of simply counting dimensions recursively, you extract them into a list recursively - then throw away the list and return just its length. You are introducing a complicated middle step just to have a reason to mention `...` in there somewhere.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please refer to my original question: "How to expand array signature into parameter pack with template metaprogramming?" As I have stated several times, the rank calculation is just an example of functionality.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template <class>
struct rank;

template <typename T,size_t n>
struct rank<T[n]> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 1u> {};

template <typename T,size_t n, size_t... ns>
struct rank<T[n], ns...> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 1u + 
rank<T[ns]...>::value> {};
```

In this optimized code, the second specialization of the rank struct now takes a variadic parameter pack ns that represents the remaining dimensions of the array. The std::integral_constant is calculated using a fold expression that adds 1 to the result of the rank struct instantiated with the remaining dimensions ns.

This optimized code should have similar functionality to the original code but with potentially faster compilation times for large arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But this doesn't seem to compile for me.

Comment: Clang-cl gives: *Error : too many template arguments for class template 'rank'*